# Two Dimensional String Pass to JTable

Tags: java, swing, file-io, csv, jtable

I'm trying to take data from a CSV file, parse it to a two dimensional array and then return that to a GUI that displays it in a JTable. Doesn't seem to be going too well!

METHOD TO GET FROM CSV

```
static String[][] readGUIFromPropertyFile(String sFileName, String userName) throws FileNotFoundException
{
       String thisLine;
       String tempArray[][] = new String[20][4];
       int i = 0;
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sFileName));
        try
        {
           while((thisLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String propertyDetails[] = thisLine.split(",");

                    if (propertyDetails[0].equals(userName))
                    {
                        tempArray[i][0] = propertyDetails[1];
                        tempArray[i][1] = propertyDetails[2];
                        tempArray[i][2] = propertyDetails[3];
                        tempArray[i][3] = propertyDetails[4];
                        tempArray[i][4] = propertyDetails[5];
                        i++;
                    }
               }
           return tempArray;
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print("\nProperties do not exist\n"); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally{
            try
            {   reader.close();
            }catch (IOException e){}}
        return tempArray;
            }
}
```

CODE FOR GUI

```
else if (event.getSource() == reload)
            {
                try {
                    data = CSVWrite.readGUIFromPropertyFile(propertyFile, userName);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Properties Loaded");
                    userPropertyView.add(displayProperties);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Properties Not Loaded");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

I have it working with a command interface so I know the code is working, but I have to implement both a GUI and a command line. I can write from GUI to CSV, no issue, but having trouble displaying it. I've looked into ArrayLists and I actually have a lecture on them tomorrow so that's also a possibility.

I can't use OpenCSV as I have to use default libraries for this.

Comment: 1) *"having trouble displaying it."*  What trouble? 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) There is no need for more than one line of blank 'white-space.

Comment: Trouble as in it's not displaying it or anything. The button doesn't seem to do anything, and the listener is active on it.

Comment: You haven't done anything with "data" in reload action. Either fill it to table or TableModel of JTable.

Comment: OK..  Edit that information into the question.  When can I expect to see the result of point 2)?

Comment: here http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/read-a-data-file-into-a-jtable-3.html is an simple example additionally u can add listener.

Comment: I've done my best with it. As far I can I can tell, the error is in the CSVWrite.readGUIFromPropertyFile() method. It does not seem to be returning the value. I have changed the code a bit on the GUI and it's working now, but only displaying the default data I have placed when I initialised the string.

Answer (score 4):

- put [String tempArray[][] as JTables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) constructor [JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) directly
- better way should be to add a new row to the `TableModel`, not replace the JTable on runtime, more in tutorial [Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the Table Model. Seems like it would be a better fit.